# Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-6

This error has been posted here several times but I'm encountering something a little different. I have two Tables named `users` and `user_type`. And `users` uses a foreign key from `user_type`. I have to fetch all users and their types, I'm using Laravel's Eloquent ORM to define relationships, this is a one to one relation.

**Users Model**:

```
/**
 * Get the user type that user has.
 */
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserType', 'ut_id', 'id');
}
```

**UserType Model**:

```
/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'ut_id';

/**
 * Get the user associated with the user type.
 */
public function users(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', 'user_type_id', $this->primaryKey);
}
```

**Fetching Controller**:

```
$users = Users::all()->users;
```

According to [Laravel ORM one-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-one) I can access this method as a property, but it's showing me the defined error. I've also tried to access it as a method but it's saying:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::users does not exist.

I've also tried to fetch them by `join()` but it's returning only a few users, I don't know why:

```
$users = Users::where('id', '>', '0')
        ->join('user_type', 'user_type.ut_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select([
            'user_type.ut_name',
            'users.*'
        ])->get();
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

***P.s***: I just want to show all the users with their respective types

Comment: This may not be directly related to the problem itself, but you should omit the third parameter of `$this->hasOne()`, or pass `$this->primaryKey` to work properly, right?

Comment: Yes you're right it should be `$this->primaryKey`. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had missed the exact foreign key between your users table and usertypes table.

First, you defined the that the foreign key of your user table is 'ut_id' base of what you had in your belongsTo relationship. On this one

```
/**
 * Get the user type that user has.
 */
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserType', 'ut_id', 'id');
}
```

Second is that, in your user type model, you used a foreign key to user table named 'user_type_id', which is at first you named it as 'ut_id' in your users table. On this one

```
/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'ut_id';

/**
 * Get the user associated with the user type.
 */
public function users(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', 'user_type_id', $primaryKey);
}
```

You have to match this foreign keys you used to solve your problem.

Now, to fetch your all user with their types, your query should look like this.

```
$users = Users::with('users')->get();
```

assuming that your user table has this relationship

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserType', 'ut_id', 'id');
}
```

and your user types model has this relationshio

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', 'ut_id', $this->primaryKey);
}
```

Comment: Ok so I have switched the keys like you mentioned and they were defined wrong earlier. But the issue is still the same. It's now fetching all the data by `$users = Users::with('users')->get();` but somehow it's showing me the error when I try to fetch like this: `$users = Users::all()->users;`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: you cannot call its users directly because laravel dont know where users properties you are fetching. to use its properties you have to do it like User::find($id)->users

Comment: if this answer helped you, please mark it as answer

Comment: Please note that find() will only return one result, you said in the question you needed all users.  See my answer below on how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

**in User model**

```
public function type(){
   return $this->hasOne(UserType::class, 'id');
}
```

**in UserType Model**

```
public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relations seem to be wrong.

Users links to UserType with id to ut_id, but userType links to User with id to user_type_id

I'm pretty sure that it should be this for userTypes

```
/**
 * Get the user associated with the user type.
 */
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users', 'id', 'user_type_id');
}
```

and then this for Users

```
public function userTypes(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserType', 'user_type_id', 'id');
}
```

Then you can eager load for all the results you want...

```
$users = Users::where('id', '>', '0')
        ->with('userTypes')
        ->get();
```